# Relative paths for images in MS Access 2003 or 2010?

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to use relative path for images in MS Access 2003 or 2010?

As far as I found out it is not.

You could just play around with generating path during the runtime and make it look like it is a relative path

```
image1.Picture = <ProgramPath> & "\" & <RelativePath>
```

but doing it that way, I dont have the ability to take a look at the picture during design time. and i do really need that option!

and here is the usecase. if you know a solution, that would be great:

folderDevelopment < only accessable for developers and for playing around with new stuff
folderDevelopment\myProgram\myProgramDevelopment.mdb / accdb < testprogram
folderDevelopment\myProgram\Images < imagefolder

folderProduction < accessable for normal user
folderProduction\myProgram\Images < imagefolder for the normal user
folderProduction\myProgram\myProgramProduction.mdb / accdb < program for regular user

at some time i need to copy myProgramDevelopment.mdb, rename it to myProgramProduction.mdb
and move it to the other folder.

if i use absolute path, my links dont break but the normal user have no right to read in the folderDevelopment. so images break.

if i use pseudo relative path, the links during runtime are always perfect, but i dont have an image during design time, so its not very nice for development.

only solution I see at the moment is to use absolute paths and change them every time I make the switch (manually or with a macro), which is an option but not very nice.

why access 2003 and even 2010 dont support relative paths? that is so lame :/

Comment: Paths where? You don't identify where you are using these, so it's really quite impossible to suggest a solution.

Comment: For example as a background in a report.

Comment: No, there's no concept of relative paths in that context. You have to set the background image at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.CurrentProject.Path` will return the path of the .mdb/.accdb.  You can then use that as a base to create a "relative" path.

You cannot directly use relative paths for images in Access 2003 (I can't speak for Access 2010).  The generally accepted workaround is to set the image controls `Picture` property in the Form_Load event:

```
Me.MyImg.Picture = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\images\MyPic.jpg"
```

Comment: i know .. but that is not the point of my question. you have to read more carefully.

Comment: You said, "if i use pseudo relative path, the links during runtime are always perfect, but i dont have an image during design time, so its not very nice for development."  What exactly are you doing that you do not have an image during design time?

Comment: I leave the image source blank. Because if I link my images to the development environment and relink the path during runtime to the production environment, there is still this problem that access is trying to load all the images prior to form_open or report_open. and once someone who has no permissions for the dev environment opens the report, he/she gets an error message even though the images load afterwards.

Comment: OK.  So why can't you leave the image source blank and set it in the Form_Open or Report_Open events?  You'll just have to be careful you don't accidentally save the form or report with the image source filled in.

Comment: As for the error message that can be easily trapped and ignored.  The one thing that could cause an issue is if there is a long delay (ie, a network timeout) in trying to reach an inaccessible file.  If that's the case, you'll just have to be extra careful in making sure you don't save a dev filename in the image source field.

Comment: if i leave the image source blank, i dont have the images during designtime, because in designtime no events are triggered! no events no images! and no .. i can't tap and ignore the error :/

Comment: OK, you are talking specifically about *Design View*.  That certainly changes things.  If your users are accessing the photos via a network drive mapped to a specific letter, you might be able to recreate the path using the `subst` or `net use` commands at a command prompt.  Is this an option?

Comment: mmh interesting idea, although I like it, it is not an option because I dont have the permissions to remap folders here.